aws amplify authorization allow.ownersDefinedIn("authors") identityClaim by email not hash id
got simple aws amplify app with schema below:
const schema = a.schema({
  Book: a
    .model({
      status: a.string(),
      person: a.string(),
      dob: a.date(),
      bookReleaseDate: a.date(),
      colorVariant: a.enum(["red", "blue", "green"]),
      title: a.string(),
      owner: a.string(),
      pages: a.hasMany("Page", "bookId"),
      authors: a.string().array(),
    })
    .authorization((allow) => [
     allow.owner(),
     allow.ownersDefinedIn("authors").identityClaim("email").to(["read"]),
    ]),

  Page: a
    .model({
      bookId: a.id(),
      book: a.belongsTo("Book", "bookId"),
      question: a.string(),
      answer: a.string(),
      imageUrl: a.string(),
      ownerEmail: a.string(),
    })
    .authorization((allow) => [allow.owner()]),
});


export type Schema = ClientSchema<typeof schema>;

export const data = defineData({
  schema,
  authorizationModes: {
    defaultAuthorizationMode: "userPool",
  },
});

as book owner i would like to be able to add authors so they can have read access to my book seems easy as I can just update authors array with ids.
worked fine as long in authors array i have long hash ID for example "9672f214-8041-7039-12ae-de999421dfb5" but when i try to add email address it does not work
issue i have is that as book owner i would like to invite people to see book but the only thing i know at that moment is email address of friends i would like to invite.
there is also chance that that user is not even exist in my app yet so not possible to add his hashid.
I had hope this would work:
allow.ownersDefinedIn("authors").identityClaim('email').to(["read"])
but it does not am I missing something?
